# Heroku database backup storage when database is not active

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm considering using Heroku as a platform for a project I'm working on.  This project will have many independent databases (postgres).  Each database will spin up when someone is using it, then save the data to a dump file and spin down when no one is logged on (if all these databases are always active it will be colossally expensive).

Unfortunately I have no experience with Heroku and their documentation has an annoying marketing slant to it--I can't figure out if this is possible.  How do I pay for the storage of backups?  Is it possible to store backups without an associated running database?

My alternative is to build this on Amazon, but I'd rather not do all this engineering myself.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Postgres Schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) approach might fit well for your example of multi-tenacy.

This [Blog Post](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/) and [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql) might help you further.

Spinning up multiple databases sounds like fighting the defaults, for which concerns?

Comment: Wow.  I Don't know how I hadn't found that postgres feature yet.  Thanks so much.